# htaccess rewrite index.php on root and subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, indexing, url-rewriting, clean-urls

I'm trying to redirect all requests to ./index.php?site=$1 while I only want to use the part behind the last slash.

So I want `www.mydomain.com/firstpage` to become `www.mydomain.com/index.php?site=firstpage` and www.mydomain.com/subfolder/anotherpage to become `www.mydomain.com/subfolder/index.php?site=anotherpage`

But right now `www.mydomain.com/subfolder/anotherpage` becomes 
`www.mydomain.com/index.php?site=subfolder/anotherpage`

This is what I've got:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?site=$1 [L]
```

What could I do to redirect only the part after the last slash?
Thank you so much!

---

#### SOLUTION:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*/)?([^/]+)$ $1index.php?site=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this other, on my opinion more elegant solution. By this, the number of subfolders is irrelevant.

---

#### SOLUTION:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*/)?([^/]+)$ $1index.php?site=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the answer myself.
At first I tried putting more RewriteRules under the same RewriteCond-lines gave me server errors. So I duplicated the RewriteCond-lines for the subdirectories:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $1/index.php?site=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?site=$1 [L]
```